# Minimum hardware requirenment for magento 2

Tags: magento2

What should be the minimum configuration of the system (Laptop or PC) to run `Magento 2` smoothly ? specially processor (Intel).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- Operating System

If you are willing to use Magento 2.0 then your’s OS should be: Linux (x86 – 64)

- Memory Requirement

To have a seamless performance of “Magento 2.0 application” then the RAM should be 2 GB. Along with this, you have to create a SWAP file so that your upgrade never fails.

- Composer

Composer is for developers who want to contribute to the Magento “codebase” or build their own “extensions”.

- Database

Databases that meet Magento requirements:

- MySQL 5.6
- MariaDB and Percona are also supported due to MySQL 5.6 APIs

- PHP Versions

Magento 2 PHP versions:
5.5.22–5.5.x, 5.6.x, 7.0.2, 7.0.6–7.0.x

- Required PHP Extensions

- PHP extensions also known as PHP libraries that are convenient for developers in terms of development.
- bc-math (Magento Commerce only), curl, gd, ImageMagick 6.3.7 (or later) or both, intl, mbstring, mcrypt, hash, openssl, PDO/MySQL, SimpleXML, soap, xml, xsl, zip, PHP 7 only: json, iconv
- So these extensions have different functionalities for e.g if you want to use “xsl” extension, it helps to read and execute the documents that are in .xsl format.

- PHP OPcache

OPcache helps to improve the performance of PHP by storing the “precompiled script” in shared memory. Hence, it reduces the time for loading the script on each request.

Therefore, it is necessary to enable the OPcache to have maximum performance.

- PHP settings

Magento recommends PHP setting to avoid common problems such as memory_limit.

[Getting Reference](https://www.cloudways.com/blog/magento-requirements/)

Comment: i am using windows 10 and what about the processor?

Comment: core i3 processor is better .

Comment: Alright. Thanks :)